# interface data in another interface in java

Tags: java, interface

I have two interfaces `Interface1` and `Interface2` as below:

```
public interface Interface1 {
  int x = 10 ;
}

public interface Interface2 {
  int y = 20
}
```

I want to call the `Interface2` value of `y` in `Interface1`. Is it possible? if yes can you tell me the way.

Comment: `int x = Interface2.y;`?

Comment: Have you tried to do some reading on java interfaces? Remember you got google available to your disposal

Comment: Note that those two variables are in fact constants. By convention, they should thus be named `X` and `Y`, in uppercase.

Comment: Yes why not.. try `x=Interface2.y` by default you define public static final constants in interface.

Answer (score 1):

Fields in interfaces are implicitly `public` `static` and `final`.

Just reference `Interface2.y`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to add a `y` to `Interface1` based on `y` from `Interface2`. That might look like,

```
public interface Interface1 {
    int x = 10 ;
    int y = Interface2.y;
}
```

Alternatively, you could extend `Interface2` like

```
public interface Interface1 extends Interface2 {
    int x = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also nest interfaces like:

```
public interface A {
    int a = 0;
    interface B{
        int b = 0;
        int c = a;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply do in this way,

```
public interface Interface2{
  int Y = 20
 }

public interface Interface1 extends Interface2 {
  int X = 10 ;
//The member 'Y' will be available here, you can simply make use of it you don't need to call like Interface2.Y.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

public interface Interface1 extends interface2
{

```
int x = 10;
```

}

public interface Interface2{

```
 int y = 20
```

}

public class temp
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println(interface1.x);

}
```

}